# Private transaction failing with Non-200 status code

Tags: web3js, quorum, azure

I have a Quorum network running on Azure Blockchain service.

Sending private messages to a particular public key is failing. It was working till last week. No code or configuration changes have been made.

The exact same code works if we use the public key of another node on the network or even if we skip the privateFor parameter completely(as in a public transaction).

We get the same error message if we use any random public key. So it seems something is wrong with the public key. These nodes have been running fine for weeks now.

**Code**

```js
const Web3 = require('web3')
const fs = require('fs')

const rpcURL = "https://<myNode1>.blockchain.azure.com:3200/<Accesskey>"

const web3 = new Web3(rpcURL)

const account = '<myAccount>'
const accountPassword = '<pwd>'

const contractByteCode = fs.readFileSync('myContractBytecodeFile.json','UTF-8');

(async() => {
    await web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(account, accountPassword, 10);

    const txCount = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account);
    console.log("txCount=",txCount);

    const txObject = {
        from: account,
        nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
        gas: web3.utils.toHex(3000000),
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0', 'gWei')),
        data: contractByteCode,
        privateFor: ['<myNode2PublicKey>']
    }

    const tx = await web3.eth.sendTransaction(txObject);
    console.log(tx);
})();
```

**Error**

```
(node:1184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Returned error: Non-200 status code: &{Status:500 Internal Server Error StatusCode:500 Proto:HTTP/1.1 ProtoMajor:1 ProtoMinor:1 Header:map[Content-Length:[39] Server:[Jetty(9.4.z-SNAPSHOT)] Date:[Mon, 24 Feb 2020 11:49:21 GMT] Content-Type:[text/plain]] Body:0xc423f8a640 ContentLength:39 TransferEncoding:[] Close:false Uncompressed:false Trailer:map[] Request:0xc42095f800 TLS:<nil>}
```

If i send the message to node2, privateFor node1, i get the below error :

```
(node:32100) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Returned error: Post http+unix://c/sendraw: dial unix /working-dir/c/tm.ipc: connect: connection refused
```

But i can connect to the Quorum node. So nothing wrong with the node itself. Something wrong with Tessera?

I went through this post, but could not make any sense of it : https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/issues/64#issuecomment-281126604

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed with the Azure blockchain team that the Tessera node had crashed. Pasting the response here verbatim :

*This was happening as the tessera on the member crashed and as you are on older ABS version where we had one issue that tessera was not auto restarted in case of crash( this issue has been fixed in latest ABS version). I have fixed the node by restarting tessera. 
Also I will suggest to you do your testing on standard member as on basic member memory is 4GB and chances of crashes are more as both geth and tessera. We recommend to do this testing on standard member.*